# CVS and pserver

Tags: cvs

Recently I am forced to migrate an ancient CVS installation from ubuntu to CentOS.

I am using 'cvsnt' from 'March Hare'. I am trying to reproduce this old legacy server's function on my relatively new CentOS box.

I have got cvslockd running, everything seems to be listening correctly, but after I do my export like:

```
export CVSROOT=:pserver:username@127.0.0.1:/somerepo
cvs login
```

I get the error:

> cvs [login aborted]: Unknown command: `pserver'

My xinet.d conf is like:

```
server_args = --allow-root=/somerepo -f pserver
```

My question is: how can I resolve the above error and get pserver method working properly?

```
[root@det1svn01 testuser]# cvs info
Available protocols:

local               (internal)
server              server 2.8.01 (Soolin) Build 5590
pserver             pserver 2.8.01 (Soolin) Build 5590
sspi                sspi 2.8.01 (Soolin) Build 5590
ext                 ext 2.8.01 (Soolin) Build 5590
```

Comment: How are you even inserting tab? it is escaping me out of the text field, I only got it by copy paste.

Comment: ok thanks  (15 character for minimum character limit)

Comment: Where are you running `cvs login`?  Is it on the Windows side with `cvsnt`?  Please make it clear which machine you're running each command on.

Comment: I'm running it from the same CVS server, just using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Oh, so you're running CVSNT on CentOS?  The name was confusing. :)

Comment: Yes apparently it became a licensed product under 'march hare' at some point. It functions just like cvs, but has some additional features.